# how do i keep the session permanent with servicestack

Tags: servicestack, basic-authentication, remember-me

I am working with a remote iPad developer who is using a tool that he says does not allow him to set the "RememberMe=true" value when registering the user.  Since we always want to have this value set anyway, I thought I could simply intercept the request on the server side and set it myself.  I am using Basic Authentication and I had already overridden "BasicAuthProvider" so I have access to the "TryAuthenticate" and "Authenticate" methods.  These methods both provide a parameter of IServiceBase which contains the original Request.  I was thinking about modifying the DTO but it is null.  So I looked at the cookie values and I could easily add a value for "ss-opt=perm" in there.  But I'm not even sure "perm" is right.

My question is this...is this the best way to set the RememberMe flag to true on the server side?  My partner says the library he is using is called "afnetworking" but that looks to be a dead end.

Marcus

EDIT: My partner found a way to set the "ss-opt" value with their tool but this does not seem to be helping.  He is still experiencing a problem after 6 hours.  There is additional information.  The first response he gets after waiting 6 hours has the "ss-pid" cookie value but the "ss-id" and "ARRAffinity" cookies are missing from the first response.  The subsequent responses has them.  Weird.

I am going to switch to using the AzureCache instead of MemCache to see if that helps.  But I did not update the server in that 6 hours so shouldn't the memory cache still have the session id values that correlate to the ss-pid value?

EDIT 2: I was under the false impression the "cache" was where the system kept the permanent ss-pid values and all I had to do was to register the cache.  How do I keep the ss-pid values around between server updates?

Comment: I am looking for "best-practices" advice.  Any thoughts?  I tried learning more about the ss-opt and RememberMe fields but there wasn't much on SS's GitHub wiki.  So I'm working a little in the dark here.  Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: demis or anyone? am i on the right path?

Comment: still hoping for a little feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to AzureCache and having the client insert the ss-opt cookie seems to be working.